# Googledrive api does not work in my azure server but it works in localhost

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, google-drive-api, access-token

i have an mvc application one of its function/method is to find a specific file called orderconformation. The method looks like this:

```
 public bool checkOrderconformation(Project project)
    {
        DriveService service = GetDriveService();
        List<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> result = new List<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File>();
        FilesResource.ListRequest request = service.Files.List();

        do
        {
            try
            {
                //all customers folder
                request.PageSize = 1000;
                request.Q = string.Format("'{0}' in parents", "0ByfIxiGuAxCEWVljS29NX2xoN1E");
                FileList files = request.Execute();
                result.AddRange(files.Files);

                //customer folder
                File customer = result.Where(f => f.Name == project.clientName).FirstOrDefault();
                request.Q = string.Format("'{0}' in parents", customer.Id);
                FileList customerFolder = request.Execute();
                result = customerFolder.Files.ToList();



                //produktions folder
                File produktion = result.Where(f => f.Name == "Produktion").FirstOrDefault();
                request.Q = string.Format("'{0}' in parents", produktion.Id);
                FileList produktionsFolder = request.Execute();
                result = produktionsFolder.Files.ToList();

                //ongoing Projects folder
                File pagaendeProjekt = result.Where(f => f.Name == "Pågående projekt").FirstOrDefault();
                request.Q = string.Format("'{0}' in parents", pagaendeProjekt.Id);
                FileList pagaendeProjektFolder = request.Execute();
                result = pagaendeProjektFolder.Files.ToList();

                //Project folder
                File Project = result.Where(f => f.Name.Contains(project.name)).FirstOrDefault();
                request.Q = string.Format("'{0}' in parents", Project.Id);
                FileList ProjektFolder = request.Execute();
                result = ProjektFolder.Files.ToList();

                //Admin folder
                File admin = result.Where(f => f.Name == "Admin").FirstOrDefault();
                request.Q = string.Format("'{0}' in parents", admin.Id);
                FileList AdminFolder = request.Execute();
                result = AdminFolder.Files.ToList();

                project.order_url = string.Format("http://www.drive.google.com/drive/folders/{0}", admin.Id);
                foreach (var item in result)
                {
                    if (item.Name.Contains("orderconformation"))
                    {

                        return true;
                    }
                }

                request.PageToken = files.NextPageToken;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
                request.PageToken = null;
            }
        } while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.PageToken));

        return false;

    }
```

because everything works in my localhost i dont think the code itself is the problem it might be some settings that i have done wrong, i dont know, anyone have any ide of what the problem might be. I suspect it might have something with something called token/ refresh token but iam not sure. You can look at the error message below[image]

Comment: Did you register your server in the URL origin in your GDC?

Comment: what do you mean? what is gdc

Comment: Google Developer Console. Since you're dealing with Google APIs, are you using any Google API Key or oAuth ClientID ?

Comment: yes i did. maybe not the best solution but it works

Comment: do you want the code? @noogui