# Google Drive API worked locally but not when deployed

Tags: c#, azure, api, asp.net-core, google-drive-api

I have a class that calls Google Drive API and then send the results to front-end. This works locally on Visual Studio. But when the project is deployed to Azure, the Google Drive API returns null.

This is the class:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace webapp {
 public class RetrieveAPIData {
  public Dictionary < string, int > GetData() {
   Dictionary < string, int > data = new Dictionary < string, int > ();
   //var certificate = ;
   //var serviceAccountEmail = ;
   //var scopes = ;
   var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail) {
    Scopes = scopes
   }.FromCertificate(certificate));

   // Create Drive API service.
   var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() {
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
     ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
   });

   // Define parameters of request.
   FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
   listRequest.PageSize = 10;
   listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(name, id)";

   // List files.
   var files = listRequest.Execute().Files;

   if (files != null && files.Count > 0) {
    foreach(var file in files) {
     data.Add(file.Name, file.Id);
    }
   }

   return data;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Is this related to your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38227014/googledrive-api-does-not-work-in-my-azure-server-but-it-works-in-localhost

Comment: What exactly returns null.?   I would be surprised that file.list returns null.  It should an object with 0 items if it finds no files. Or an error if its not able to access google drive with the service account.

Comment: That might be a dumb question but did you put the credentials and token.json in the release folder or wherever you specified the location of these files in your code? Did you include that when you uploaded your app to Azure?